# Android download and install SSL certificate

Tags: android, ssl, download, certificate, installation

How do I download a SSL certificate from a (HTTPS) website and import it to my android device? I know it's possible to download the certificate with Openssl or from the browser by clicking on the padlock left to the URL bar and then going to Certificate information -> Export to file, but what if I don't have an PC or Laptop around and I need to do all that directly on my Android phone?